# Add a component dynamically to a child element using a directive

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components, angular2-directives

Trying to place a component dynamically to a child element, using a directive.

The component (as template):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ps-tooltip',
  template: `
    <div class="ps-tooltip">
      <div class="ps-tooltip-content">
        <span>{{content}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class TooltipComponent {

  @Input()
  content: string;

}
```

the directive:

```
import { TooltipComponent } from './tooltip.component';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ps-tooltip]',
})
export class TooltipDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  @Input('ps-tooltip') content: string;

  private tooltip: ComponentRef<TooltipComponent>;

  constructor(
      private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
      private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
      private elRef: ElementRef,
      private renderer: Renderer
  ) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // add trigger class to el
    this.renderer.setElementClass(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'ps-tooltip-trigger', true); // ok

    // factory comp resolver
    let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(TooltipComponent);

    // create component
    this.tooltip = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
    console.log(this.tooltip);

    // set content of the component
    this.tooltip.instance.content = this.content as string;
  }
}
```

The problem is that this is creating a sibling and I want a child (see bellow)

result:

```
<a class="ps-btn ps-tooltip-trigger" ng-reflect-content="the tooltip">
  <span>Button</span>
</a>
<ps-tooltip>...</ps-tooltip>
```

wanted result:

```
<a class="ps-btn ps-tooltip-trigger" ng-reflect-content="the tooltip">
  <span>Button</span>
  <ps-tooltip>...</ps-tooltip>
</a>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: There is no way to do that. You would need a `ViewContainerRef` of a child where the added component can be a sibling of. That's how `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Can I ask what you suggest to get the desired result?!

Answer (score 15):

Even dynamic component is inserted as sibling element you can still move element to desired place by using:

```
this.elRef.nativeElement.appendChild(this.tooltip.location.nativeElement);
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/1zFOv5fuL78XVbkslFqA?p=preview)**

Comment: You absolute hero!

Answer (score 3):

A better approach would be to have a nested `ng-template` with template reference variable on it such that the component is added as a sibling to `ng-template` but is now child to `ng-template`'s parent.

Your template should be

```
<div class="ps-tooltip">
  <div class="ps-tooltip-content">
    <span>{{content}}</span>
    <ng-template #addHere></ng-template>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in your component

```
@ViewChild('addHere') addHere: ViewContainerRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    ...

    this.tooltip = addHere.createComponent(factory)

    ...
}
```